# Convolution only around nonzero values?

Tags: python, convolution

Is there a convolution in any python library with which I can only convolve around nonzero entries in my matrix?

With convolution, I mean something like `scipy.ndimage.convolve` - but here I dont have this option.

Here is an example:

```
matrix = np.array([[ 0, 0, 0],
                   [ 0, 0, 0],
                   [ 0, 1, 1],
                   [ 0, 0, 0],
                   [ 0, 0, 0]])

kernel = np.array([[ 0, -1,  0],
                   [-1,  4, -1],
                   [ 0, -1,  0]])
```

I want to convolve only around the entries with a 1 in the matrix
to avoid applying the operator to zero regions to reduce the computational burden

Comment: I think maybe you need to explain what you mean by convolving around nonzero entries.

Comment: I add an example, is it clear now?

Comment: Well, applying your operator to the matrix maps patches which are all 0's to 0's, and there are nonzero results only in neighborhoods containing nonzero values. So you get nonzero results at or near nonzero elements by just doing the usual convolution, right? Are you wanting to avoid applying the operator to zero regions to reduce the computational burden? Maybe you can say more about what your larger goal is.

Comment: Are you wanting to avoid applying the operator to zero regions to reduce the computational burden? --> thats exactly what i want to do

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Convolution is typically implemented via FFT, which is much faster than straightforward applying the patch operator repeatedly. However, FFT is going to touch every value, so, from what I know, there's always the same number of calculations. If you want to restrict the convolution to certain regions, you might have to do it yourself, e.g. determining bounding regions and then applying ordinary FFT-based convolution within those. But maybe a web search for "sparse convolution" or related terms will bring up something.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you need to do that? Is the FFT-based convolution really the bottleneck in your application? Maybe you can explain what is the overall goal.

Comment: Please show concrete proof that you're hitting a performance bottleneck before you try to micro-optimize: numpy and scipy are _incredibly good_ at their job, and even convolving a 100,000,000 element matrix with a 3x3 kernel on a cpu that was good for computation 5 year ago but is hopelessly outdated today takes barely any time at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just use fancy index assignment to reset all the "these should stay zero" to zero:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

matrix = np.array([[ 0, 0, 0],
                   [ 0, 0, 0],
                   [ 0, 1, 1],
                   [ 0, 0, 0],
                   [ 0, 0, 0]])

kernel = np.array([[ 0, -1,  0],
                   [-1,  4, -1],
                   [ 0, -1,  0]])

convolved = convolve(matrix, kernel)

"""
this will yield: array([[ 0,  0,  0],
                        [ 0, -1, -1],
                        [-1,  3,  2],
                        [ 0, -1, -1],
                        [ 0,  0,  0]])
"""

convolved[matrix == 0] = 0

"""
this is now: array([[0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 3, 2],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]])
"""
```

Comment: I would like to obtain the same result i would get with convolve(matrix, kernel)

Comment: That is mathematically impossible, so you're going to have to do a much better job at explaining what you need. Convolution performs a weighted sum computation on every element in the matrix, based on however many elements your kernel consists of. You can't "get the same result" _and_ "ignore all zeroes". If you just want to "avoid computation", then first prove to yourself that you're actually wasting time, because numpy is highlight efficient, and you're almost certainly not.